# En Flutter no me permite cambiar las propiedad del Textfield (quitar border y colors ) cuando es llamado desde otra pantalla con showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

```
// llamada a otra pantalla desde aqui
void _settingModalBottomSheetTratamiento(context){
    **showModalBottomSheet**(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
           return Container(
              child:  Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                     leading: Icon(Icons.medical_services_rounded,color: Colors.blue,),
                     title: Text('Agregar Medicina'),
                     onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      **Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddTratamientoScreen.routeName);**
                     }        
                 ),
            ],
          ),
          );
      }
    );   
}

// segunda pantalla
Flexible(
  child: TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: _controllerDosis,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        ***border: InputBorder.none,***
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),)))
```

Nota: No tengo border definido pero muestra esto

Comment: por favor explica mejor el problema que presentas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la respuesta,usaba themes() en la página principal incluido la propiedad para Texto la cual se heredaba en todas las páginas, quité  la parte de decoración:

inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationTheme(), y pude establecer mi propia decoración para campos TEXTFIELD